# Everything is working properly, but suddenly mongo error came out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the error:

```
MongoError: user account has been updated after reload. Please reauthenticate the user
  File "/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js", line 268, in MessageStream.messageHandler
    callback(new MongoError(document));
  File "node:events", line 369, in MessageStream.emit
  File "node:domain", line 470, in MessageStream.emit
  File "/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js", line 144, in processIncomingData
    stream.emit(
  File "/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js", line 42, in MessageStream._write
    processIncomingData(this, callback);
```

Any help about what this happened is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue just now. I was able to fix that by just restarting the server and reconnecting to Mongo, but still looking for the reason why that happened.

Comment: Since I was using heroku, it restarted again without any more problems.